# Agregar resultado como única fila a una consulta sql con multiple resultados

Tags: oracle, sql

buenas tardes.
Quiero contarles que necesitamos migrar unos datos de una BD Oracle a MySQL y estoy luchando con una consulta.

Por un lado en ORACLE tengo 2 tablas
  * Tabla 1 DOC (encabezado de documento)
  * Tabla 2 DOCDET (detalle de los documentos)

Desde la tabla 1 (DOC), tengo especificamente 1 dato **(rc.cond COND)** en esta tabla (Oracle) sólo existe una condicion de pago por cada documento.
quisiera construir la consulta para obtener los datos de la tabla 2, y mostrarla como 1 fila y no como una columna.

CÓDIGO que ahora uso para obtener los datos de la tabla 2 (reducido para este ejemplo)

---

```sql
-- USED SQLquery 4 tr_Real
SELECT rc.cond, tr.tdoc,tr.kdoc, tr.dcmp, tr.kcmp -- vars
FROM DOCDET tr
    INNER JOIN DOC rc
    ON ( tr.kemp = rc.kemp AND tr.tdoc = rc.tdoc AND tr.kdoc = rc.kdoc ) -- match
WHERE
    tr.kemp = '003' AND tr.kdoc IN (46642,1881570) -- empresa y registro especifico
    AND tr.femi >= TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') -- periodo inicio
    AND tr.femi <= TO_DATE('2019-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD') -- periodo fin
    AND tr.tdoc IN ('FAE','BOL','CRE') --documentos especificos
ORDER BY tr.femi DESC, tr.kdoc, tr.line ASC;
```

**RESULTADO ACTUAL:**
[image: resultado actual]

**RESULTADO ESPERADO:**
la columna COND (TARJETA)
[image: resultado esperado]

acepto sugerencias.
Gracias.
Héctor

Comment: El TAG de tu pregunta es Oracle, pero mencionas en el cuerpo MySQL, al final, no me queda claro para qué motor es que buscas la consulta que te de ese resultado.

Comment: gracias jachguate por el interes, la consulta es para Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando un CTE, puedes construir al vuelo una *vista* que añada las filas que tu quieres.

La idea es:

- en el primer CTE, llamado `BaseReporte`, tengo tu consulta original, más algunas columnas que son necesarias luego para el ordenamiento y que tu no incluías: `femi`, `line` y sin el ordenamiento.
- en el CTE `BaseLineaExtra`, creo las filas que me servirán de base para crear las líneas *extra* que tu quieres, por cada condición de pago que se encuentra. Para que la línea quede bien intercalada, le doy una fecha ficticia que es un día antes de la primera fecha del grupo. Con esto me aseguro que, al hacer el ordenamiento final por `fecha desc` se intercalará al final de cada grupo, como se ve en tu ejemplo.
- el CTE `Reporte` simplemente une las filas del CTE original, con las filas a intercalar. Acá, en la consulta que va después del `union all` voy a crear tantos campos como sea necesario para que tengan la misma estructura de columnas del CTE `BaseReporte`, de manera que sea posible hacer la operación de unión.
- finalmente hago una consulta sobre esta vista `Reporte`, asegurándome de ordenar los resultados correctamente.

Es, quizás, más fácil verlo en código:

```
with
BaseReporte as (
SELECT rc.cond, tr.tdoc,tr.kdoc, tr.dcmp, tr.kcmp, tr.femi, tr.line -- vars
FROM DOCDET tr
    INNER JOIN DOC rc
    ON ( tr.kemp = rc.kemp AND tr.tdoc = rc.tdoc AND tr.kdoc = rc.kdoc ) -- match
WHERE
    tr.kemp = '003' AND tr.kdoc IN (46642,1881570) -- empresa y registro especifico
    AND tr.femi >= TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') -- periodo inicio
    AND tr.femi <= TO_DATE('2019-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD') -- periodo fin
    AND tr.tdoc IN ('FAE','BOL','CRE') --documentos especificos
)
,
BaseLineaExtra as (
select cond, min(femi) - 1 femi 
  from BaseReporte
 group by cond
)
,
Reporte as (
select *
  from BaseReporte
union all
select cond, null, null, cond, cond, femi, 0
  from BaseLineaExtra
)
select cond, tdoc, kdoc, dcmp, kcmp 
  from Reporte
ORDER BY cond, femi DESC, kdoc, line ASC;
```

Esto debiera producir un resultado como este:

```
cond     tdoc kdoc     dcmp                                       kcmp
-------- ---- -------- ------------------------------------------ --------
EFECTIVO FAE  00046642 SPRAY PICK-UP NEGRO                        1274002
EFECTIVO FAE  00046642 PIST CALAFATEAR NARANJA                    1274002
EFECTIVO NULL NULL     EFECTIVO                                   EFECTIVO
TARJETA  BOL  01881570 20 X 30 BLANCO BR. SODI. 1,50 CJ.          5420507
TARJETA  BOL  01881570 20 X 30 MARMOL GRIS 1,50 CJ CHINO IMPERIAL 5420506
TARJETA  BOL  01881570 LAT 4G LTEX MULTICOLOR P SIPA              2311101
TARJETA  NULL NULL     TARJETA                                    TARJETA

(7 rows affected)
```

<del>*Advertencia*: No tengo oracle a mano, he tratado de escribir una consulta que considero que debe ejecutarse sin problemas, pero he utilizado otro motor para probar mis ideas.</del>

Edit: Finalmente he podido probarlo en el Oracle Live, lo puedes probar directamente [en línea](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ib0v88s1o18p8dev4uxhhd9r0)

Comment: hola @jachguate, gracias por la dedicación, como no soy muy habil en Oracle probé el código tal cual lo indicas y obtuve el siguiente mensaje:  
`ORA-01790: la expresión debe tener el mismo tipo de dato que la expresión correspondiente
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 21, columna: 8
`

Comment: Esto se debe a que no hay compatibilidad en los tipos de dato de la consulta, lo que me parece extraño es que la consulta de la línea 21 solamente tiene 7 campos, no 8.